# template_redirect action only firing if logged in

Tags: functions, redirect, actions

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'add_header_redirect', 0, 0);
function add_header_redirect(){
    if( is_page(array(8, 'testimonials', 'Testimonials')) ){
        $default_testimonial = get_permalink( 19 );
        header("Location: $default_testimonial");
    }
}
```

this code is in my functions.php file and ONLY works when I am logged into WP. I want all users who go to /testimonials to be redirected. what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with WP-Super-Cache plugin. When I was logged in, it wasn't serving me a cached file, so my template redirect was being executed. Not sure if this is a known liability with WP-Super-Cache.

My solution was to make a template for page-testimonials.php where I set up my PHP redirect. After flushing the cache, the redirect works.

Comment: Thank you, I never would have figured this out. In my case just setting my `template_redirect` action to priority 1 resolved it.